# Computing standard deviation from bursts of data

Tags: sampling, standard-deviation

This is my first question on CrossValidated Exchange!

I seek help and pointers on proper terminology or other references, with respect to the following challenge I have.

I have a time series of data that represents distance measurements in meters (taken with a laser). The data is produced with a mechanism that is outside of my control. This means that I do not have knowledge of the sampling time between each measurement. However, I know that the data is collected in "bursts"; a sample of the data is provided in the chart below:

[image: data sample]

From the data we observe, it is clear that each burst is centered around a different mean value, but the standard deviation of the measurements within each burst seems to be more or less the same for all bursts.

**Question:** How can I compute the standard deviation of all the measurements by removing the "bias" that the mean value of each burst is centered about? Would it be scientifically valid to compute the mean of the standard deviations of each burst? If yes, how can I properly group those burst in order to compute the "local" standard deviation of each burst and then average them out? How is this problem called?

My background is in aerospace engineering, but my statistics may be rusty at least, Thank you in advace for your help!

Kind regards,
Emmanuel

Comment: I guess that the observation within a burst all estimate the same distance, but do the three bursts also estimate that same distance?

Comment: Yes @MichaelLew, they do measure the same distance. The measurements are in fact laser distance measurements from a ground station to a reflective satellite in space, hence their variation in the order of 0 to 40 meters. Any help or terminology is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Presumably the distance from the laser to the satellite varies with time. Is the time between measurements so small as to make the orbital path irrelevant?

Comment: It is not unusual to make multiple measurements during an 'observation' and then taking the mean of that as the datum. That reduces the influence of measurement noise. In biomedical science we might take observations 'in triplicate', for example. The biological variability would then be calculated from the standard deviation of the means of those triplicate observations.

Comment: The distance to the satellite varies with time indeed, but as you correctly pointed out, the time between measurements is sufficiently small that the orbital path changes are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for confirming another use-case in biomedical science. In this case, I seek to find the mean of the standard deviations of each burst, so that I can use that value in a Batch Least Squared process for Orbit Determination. The value I seek to capture should physically represent the measurement noise of the whole setup. I am loonging into an automated process to "group" those bursts. I am thinking of producing a histogram and evaluate the first mode. That value with some margins, should represent the threshold for idintifying the groups of bursts. Would that be correct, I wonder...